# Qt cannot connect to the server

Tags: qt, network-programming

I am trying to create simple server that will just show when somebody have connected to me. Everything works fine when client and server use "localhost" as a host name to connect, but when I changed localhost to my ip address then I got timeout error :(
There is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
    server_status=0;
}

void MainWindow::on_starting_clicked()
{
    tcpServer = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(tcpServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(newuser()));
    if (!tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 33333) && server_status==0) {
        qDebug() <<  QObject::tr("Unable to start the server: %1.").arg(tcpServer->errorString());
        ui->textinfo->append(tcpServer->errorString());
    } else {
        server_status=1;
        qDebug() << tcpServer->isListening() << "TCPSocket listen on port";
        ui->textinfo->append(QString::fromUtf8("Server started!"));
        qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("Server started!");
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_stoping_clicked()
{
    if(server_status==1){
        foreach(int i,SClients.keys()){
            QTextStream os(SClients[i]);
            os.setAutoDetectUnicode(true);
            os << QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString() << "\n";
            SClients[i]->close();
            SClients.remove(i);
        }
        tcpServer->close();
        ui->textinfo->append(QString::fromUtf8("Server stopped!"));
        qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("Server stopped!");
        server_status=0;
    }
}


void MainWindow::newuser()
{
    if(server_status==1){
        qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8("New connection!");
        ui->textinfo->append(QString::fromUtf8("New connection!"));
        QTcpSocket* clientSocket=tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
        int idusersocs=clientSocket->socketDescriptor();
        SClients[idusersocs]=clientSocket;
        connect(SClients[idusersocs],SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(slotReadClient()));
    }
}
```

And for client:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->connectToHost("95.220.162.117", 33333);
    socket->waitForConnected();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I am a novice in the field of working with network, so please explain me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Sounds like a firewall is blocking you. What OS is the server on?

Comment: OSX 10.9 and firewall is off

Comment: When using localhost to connect the firewall rules generally allow everything through back to itself. When connecting from an external network interface - firewall rules help prevent intrusions. Port 33333 is a port you will have to unblock in the firewall settings. This [Apple how to](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht1810) may help you open up the port for usage.

Comment: Ah missed the "firewall is off" oops. I just saw OS/X ;-) . I assume you mean the firewall is off on the server? Probably not a good idea if it is sitting on the public internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"95.220.162.117" looks like a public European IP address. This public IP address is shared by all the computers/tablets/phones/etc. in your home/office. Think of it this way: The public IP address points to your router, not to a specific computer.

When a client sends a request to a public IP address, the router receives the request first. It is then the router's job to forward the request to the correct device... but in your case, your router doesn't know which device should receive the request!

There are two levels to making your connection work:

**1. Private: Within your local network (Easier)**

On your server, open your console and enter the following to find your private/local IP address:

```
ifconfig -a
```

Your local IP address is different from your public IP address. It identifies a specific computer on your local network. Make your client connect to this address, and your server should receive the request.

This only works when the client and the server are on the same local network (e.g. connected to the same router)

**2. Public: Over the internet (Harder)**

You need to set up [Port Forwarding](http://portforward.com/) -- This tells your router to take requests received at port 33333 and forward them to your server.

To learn more about this topic, read up on [Network Address Translation](http://whatismyipaddress.com/nat).